# IllegalArgumentException: 'dataSource' or 'jdbcTemplate' is required when extending JdbcUserDetailsManager

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, datasource

I´m pretty new to Spring, and I´m currently struggling with an exception being thrown when I´m attempting to extend JdbcUserDetailsManager since I need additional features besides the ones provided. The class signature looks looks like this, with a default constructor.

```
@Repository
public class PrimeUserDetailsManager extends JdbcUserDetailsManager implements CustomUserDetailsManager {

    public static String CUSTOM_USERS_BY_USERNAME_QUERY = "select username,password,enabled from users where username like ?%";  
    public static String FIND_ALL_USERS_QUERY = "select username,password,enabled from users";

    @Override
    public List<UserDetails> loadUsersByUsername(String username) {
        return super.loadUsersByUsername(username);
    }

    @Override
    public List<UserDetails> findAllUsers() {
        return getJdbcTemplate().query(FIND_ALL_USERS_QUERY, new RowMapper<UserDetails>() {
            public UserDetails mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                String username = rs.getString(1);
                String password = rs.getString(2);
                boolean enabled = rs.getBoolean(3);
                return new User(username, password, enabled, true, true, true, AuthorityUtils.NO_AUTHORITIES);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

My custom Interfaces looks like this:

```
public interface CustomUserDetailsManager extends UserDetailsManager {
    public List<UserDetails> loadUsersByUsername(String username);
    public List<UserDetails> findAllUsers();
}
```

Simple autowire:

```
@Service("userService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

    @Autowired
    public UserServiceImpl(CustomUserDetailsManager customUserDetailsManager) {
        this.customUserDetailsManager = customUserDetailsManager;
    }

    private CustomUserDetailsManager customUserDetailsManager;
    ....
}
```

And in my ApplicationContext, I have this:

```
<beans:bean id="jdbcUserService" class="org.primefaces.examples.moviecollector.custom.PrimeUserDetailsManager">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <beans:property name="enableGroups" value="true"/>
    <beans:property name="enableAuthorities" value="false"/>
</beans:bean>
```

Still, when staring my application, I get the exception below, so apperently I must have missed something? Can someone please tell me what?

Complete stacktrack:

```
2011-sep-07 13:08:49 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
ALLVARLIG: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userBean' defined in file [C:\Program\springsource\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.5.0.RELEASE\Localhost\wtpwebapps\prime-sweet\WEB-INF\classes\org\primefaces\examples\moviecollector\beans\UserBean.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.security.provisioning.GroupManager]: : Error creating bean with name 'primeUserDetailsManager' defined in file [C:\Program\springsource\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.5.0.RELEASE\Localhost\wtpwebapps\prime-sweet\WEB-INF\classes\org\primefaces\examples\moviecollector\custom\PrimeUserDetailsManager.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'dataSource' or 'jdbcTemplate' is required; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'primeUserDetailsManager' defined in file [C:\Program\springsource\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.5.0.RELEASE\Localhost\wtpwebapps\prime-sweet\WEB-INF\classes\org\primefaces\examples\moviecollector\custom\PrimeUserDetailsManager.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'dataSource' or 'jdbcTemplate' is required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:730)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1003)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:907)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5204)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5199)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'primeUserDetailsManager' defined in file [C:\Program\springsource\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.5.0.RELEASE\Localhost\wtpwebapps\prime-sweet\WEB-INF\classes\org\primefaces\examples\moviecollector\custom\PrimeUserDetailsManager.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'dataSource' or 'jdbcTemplate' is required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:844)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:786)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:795)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:723)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'dataSource' or 'jdbcTemplate' is required
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.JdbcDaoSupport.checkDaoConfig(JdbcDaoSupport.java:112)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DaoSupport.afterPropertiesSet(DaoSupport.java:44)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    ... 34 more
```

EDIT:
I´ve included the entire body of PrimeUserDetailsManager above. Here´s the dataSource definition:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" >
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: where is the `dataSource` defined?

Comment: Provide source for CustomUserDetailsManager, at least constructor, if any, and fields.

Comment: @Bozho: I assumed that dataSource was inherited from JdbcUserDetailsManager, but looks like I´m wrong... So I guess I just add it to the PrimeUserDetailsManager?

Comment: @mgamulin: The entire CustomerUserDetailsManager is available in my first post.

Comment: Oh sorry: <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" >
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
    </bean>

Comment: Sorry, don´t have the previlige to update my first post :-/

Comment: Sorry, I ment PrimeUserDetailsManager

Comment: `Error creating bean with name 'primeUserDetailsManager'`  Can you post the definition of this bean in Spring?

Comment: I´ll add more info tomorrow, but I suspect the problem is with the bean definition.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've got two beans. One is defined in XML. There's another one being created because you've annotated your class with `@Repository`. That's the one giving you the trouble because you haven't given it any instructions about wiring the required "'dataSource' or 'jdbcTemplate'". Note in the exception that the bean's name is given as "primeUserDetailsManager". That's the lower-cased simple class name, which is the default name for beans [created via component scanning with annotations](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config).

Comment: Ah, my lack of knowledge with Spring. Guess I´ll have to take another look at the reference manual :-) Cheers!

Answer (score 7):

I create an intermediate **JdbcDaoSupport** derived super class that all my DAO classes **extend** from that looks like this:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.JdbcDaoSupport;

public class MyJdbcDaoSupport extends JdbcDaoSupport {
    @Autowired private DataSource dataSource;
    @PostConstruct
    private void initialize() {
        setDataSource(dataSource);
    }
}
```

This assumes you have a data source bean with id  "dataSource", as shown by the OP.

Works for me in Spring 4.x but should work with earlier versions too.

Comment: This solution works also for Spring 5.0.8. MyDao class extends JdbcDatoSupport and implements an interface.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I managed to solve is by defining following in my DAO.

```
 private SimpleJdbcTemplate simpleJdbcTemplate;

    protected SimpleJdbcTemplate getSimpleJdbcTemplate() {
        return simpleJdbcTemplate;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.simpleJdbcTemplate = new SimpleJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
```

It seems the SimpleJdbcDaoSupport does not have @Autowired annotation to its setDataSource method.

Answer (score 1):

This works even in spring 2.5

```
/**
 * Sets the parent class DataSource to the auto-wired data source.
 * 
 * 
 */
@Autowired
public void setParentDataSource(
        @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    super.setDataSource(dataSource);
}
```